# new SoapClient() not working within class

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am new with SoapClient(). I have a code which I execute with normal PHP script it works fine. But when I try to put that code within class structure it throws an exception as below :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
>   WSDL: Couldn't load from '
>   https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl' in
>   C:\wamp64\www\hardik\ezidebit\lib\HDEzidebit\hd-ezidebit-payment-methods.php
>   on line 9

My code which is working is as below :

```
$url = "https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl";
$soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
$params = array(
    "digitalKey" => 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX', 
    "token" => "XXXXXX",
    "paymentAmountInCents" => "1600",
    "customerName" => "User Test",
    "paymentReference" => "1549678",
);
$response = $soapclient->ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($params);
```

And class which I have written is as below :

```
<?php
class HDEziDebit{
    public $DigitalKey = '';
    public $PublicKey = '';
    //public $PciMode = '';
    public $Environment = '';

    public $pciURL = '';
    public $nonpciURL = '';
    public $pulicRestURL = '';

    public function __construct($DigitalKey, $PublicKey, $Environment){
        // if (! in_array($PciMode, array('pci', 'nonpci','public-rest'))) {
        //  throw new Exception("Invalid PCI mode");
        // }
        if (! in_array($Environment, array('live', 'test'))) {
            throw new Exception('Invalid environment');
        }
        $this->DigitalKey = $DigitalKey;
        $this->Environment = $Environment;
        $this->PublicKey = $PublicKey;
        $this->initializeConfigurations();
    }

    public function initializeConfigurations(){
        $domain = '';
        switch ($this->Environment) {
            case 'live':
                $domain = 'https://api.ezidebit.com.au';
                break;
            default:
                $domain = ' https://api.demo.ezidebit.com.au';
                break;
        }
        $this->pciURL = $domain.'/v3-5/pci?singleWsdl';
        $this->nonpciURL = $domain.'v3-5/nonpci';
        $this->pulicRestURL = $domain.'/V3-5/public-rest';
    }
}


class paymentMethods{
    private $HDEziDebit;
    public function __construct($HDEziDebit){
        $this->HDEziDebit = $HDEziDebit;
    }

    public function createSoapClient($url){
        $soapclient = new SoapClient($url);
        return $soapclient;
    }

    public function getSoapClientResponse($soapclient){
        $response = $soapclient->__getLastResponse();
        return $response;
    }

    public function ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($parameters){
        $soapclient = $this->createSoapClient($this->HDEziDebit->pciURL);
        $params = array(
          "digitalKey" => $this->HDEziDebit->DigitalKey, 
          "token" => $parameters['token'],        // The ads ID 
          "paymentAmountInCents" => $parameters['paymentAmountInCents'],
          "customerName" => $parameters['customerName'],
          "paymentReference" => $parameters['paymentReference'],
        );
        $soapclient->ProcessRealtimeTokenPayment($params);
        return $this->getSoapClientResponse($soapclient);
    }
}
?>
```

Please help me in this issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you have HTTPS/SSL conectivity from PHP?

Comment: @Scuzzy I am working in local machine.

Comment: @Scuzzy I have also tried with SSL enabled server. But it is not working and showing same error.

Comment: Did you run working one on command line?

Comment: @mim. I am new with this so I don't know how to run command line

Comment: @Hardik i guess you have a space before your service url, can you remove it?

Comment: what happens if you reference the WSDL locally? if it works, then you've got problems downloading the WSDL programatically.

Comment: @mim. Thank you. I removed space and it working in class now.